# SSIS get data from different database

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have two database A and B 
In Database A I have a table A1 and in Database B I have a Table B1
I have the following data in A1

```
ID     |    Name    | Active
1      | Alpha      | 1
2      | Bravo      | 1
3      | Charlie    | 1
4      | Delta      | 0
5      | Echo       | 0
```

I have the following data in B1

```
ID     |A1ID     |   Name
1      | 1       | Mike
2      | 1       | November
3      | 2       | Oscar
4      | 3       | Romeo
5      | 4       | Sierra
```

I need to check what all are active in table A1 here (1,2,3)
and according to that I have to get the data from Table B1 which contains A1ID as the reference
so from table B1 i have to get the data here (1,2,3,4) records how can i do that using SSIS Package

Answer (score 0):

I have in mind two ways.

**First method if you have also different servers:**

1. Create 2 connection managers: one for A1 and second for B2.
2. Put 2 **OLE DB source** components into **Data Flow**. For B2 source select B2 table, as for A1 put something like this code:

   SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.A1 AS A
   WHERE A.Active = 1
   Order By A.ID
3. In both sources under **Show Advanced Editor** you must in **Input and Output Properties** tab: mark `IsSorted = True` **for OLE DB Source Output** and under **Output Columns** of **for OLE DB Source Output** for A1 source ID column for B1 A1ID column must have SortKeyPosition = 1
4. Add **Merge Join** component and link sources to this. Open editor and look if data connected correctly, and select what columns to show

I added **Multicast ** just to view data with **Data Viewer**
[image]

**The second method if you have data on same server:**

Create Connection manager. Just add **Ole DB source**, put this code inside it:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name AS NameA1, B.NAME AS NameB1
FROM ForTests.dbo.A1 AS A
INNER JOIN FileSearchTest.dbo.B1 AS B
    ON A.ID = B.A1ID
WHERE A.Active = 1
```

And thats it.
[image]